# Changing href attribute of a div twice with javascript does not work in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change href attribute onmouseover using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161949/how-can-i-change-href-attribute-onmouseover-using-jquery)

I need to change the href attribute of one div twice for a bilingual site. The original href attribute is assigned by a cms.

The javascript code I use is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {document.getElementById('p2749244').href='new address'});
```

I have pasted the code in two pages with a different href attribute on each page and it works fine on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Chrome.

However on IE9 the first href change is correct but for some reason it is carried over to the next page and the second change does not show up. Is there a way to fix this for IE?

EDIT
Turns out that this is happening on IE because of the cms I use.