# How can I change href attribute onmouseover using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Excuse my ignorance but I've been searching for this for a while and I can't figure out how to change the href of the following:

```
<a id="p2749244"class="nohover"onfocus="this.blur()"name="index"rel="history"onmouseout="this.className='nohover';"onmouseover="this.className='hover';"href="address">
```

What kind of selectors do I need to use to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be using `setAttribute` - although I'd go with Daniels' suggestion and use jQuery for the whole code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
onmouseover="this.href = 'urlHere';"
```

Or using jQuery, you can use the class selector.

```
$('.nohover').hover(function(){
    this.href = "urlHere";
});
```

Instead of having inline event handling use jQuery to manage it better, try this.

```
$('.nohover').hover(function(){
    $(this)
    .addClass('hover')
    .removeClass('nohover')
    .attr('href', 'urlHere');
}, function(){
    $(this)
    .addClass('nohover')
    .removeClass('hover');
}).focus(function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you do this with jquery instead? I think it might be more reliable than the old fashioned DOM method.

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#p2749244').attr('href', 'new address'); });
```

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't see how that has anything to do with the problem at all (even IE, in all its glorious crappiness, supports `getElementById`) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
onmouseover="this.href = 'blahblah'"
```

Comment: this is not jquery as asked in the question

Comment: Only difference is, this will work even if jQuery has not been included. Oh, and it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[name="index"]').hover(
function(){$(this).attr(href,'new_href_here')},
function(){//code for mouse out here}
)
```